# CherryPy application behind apache, apache serving other applications

Tags: python, apache, web-applications, virtualhost, cherrypy

What I want to do:

```
host/ --> apache
host/app1 --> apache
host/app2 --> apache --> cherrypy
```

I am totally lost between mod_rewrites, proxies, virtualhosts and locations.
Don't know how to do it. I know how to get:

```
host/ --> apache --> cherrypy
```

or even:

```
host/app2 --> apache --> cherrypy
```

but don't know how to mix everything together
Any idea?

The reason to do this is because I want to install my app (done with cherrypy) running behind an apache server that has other apps (done in PHP, perl, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a config file under httpd/conf.d/, that reads:

```
ProxyPass /app2 http://localhost/app2
ProxyPassReverse /app2 http://localhost:9091/app2
```

this is the cherrypy server:

```
http://localhost:9091
```

with an application running in /app2.

This is a reverse proxy. When client requests /app2,
the request is finally handled as

```
http://localhost:9091/app2
```

and this seems being done without the client being aware of the cherrypy server.